# Puppeteer does not recognize Firefox browser instances

Tags: node.js, firefox, websocket, puppeteer

Puppeteer keeps on recognizing existing Firefox browser instances as chrome

I am connecting puppeteer to an existing firefox browser instance with websocket and goto a page such as stackoverflow.com. But puppeteer keeps on thinking that it is chrome and when the actual firefox browser went to stackoverflow, puppeteer cannot parse whatever firefox sends back confirming that is connected to the website, so it just times out. I used the following code.

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-core"
const wsEndpointurl = 'ws://127.0.0.1:1235/devtools/browser/29c08eb1-80af-4bc0-bb23-d032b09eea53';
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: wsEndpointurl,
    product: "firefox",
    headless: false,
    
    args:[
        '-wait-for-browser'
    ],     
 });
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto('https://youtube.com')
console.log('connected')
```

timeout error

```
file:///E:/VS%20Projects/Puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/LifecycleWatcher.js:157
    return new TimeoutError(errorMessage);
           ^
TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
    at LifecycleWatcher._LifecycleWatcher_createTimeoutPromise (file:///E:/VS%20Projects/Puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/LifecycleWatcher.js:157:12)
```

Puppeteer does work with connected instances of **chrome** and **new** instances of firefox. I reinstalled the library and issue persisted, across 2 projects.